# Optimal way of searching, and removing from an array in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am wondering if I am doing something wrong in the way I am using mongoose in express. My code just doesnt look right. It takes 2 mongoose query to add something in a document, and I am wondering if this could be simplifed.

So this function would be referenced in my routes in express, how can I simplify this? It searches for the users notification document in the collection, removes something in the pending array, and saves it. I wanted to add also another 2 queries to find the users accepted request document and add the old pending document in it, but it would make a total of 4 queries and a loop in one request ... it just doesnt sound right...

```
var acceptRequest = function(userId, requesterId, callback){

    NotificationsReference.findOne({ id: userId}, function(err, result){
        if(err || result === null){
            callback("Could not accept notification. Stack: " + err);
        }
        else{
            var deletedRefId = 'unchanged';
            for(i = 0; i < result.pending.length; i++){

               if( result.pending[i].refId = requesterId){
                   //Removing searched element of the array
                   deletedRefId = result.pending.splice(i, 1);
                   result.save(function (err) {
                   if (err) { 
                        callback("Error in saving request(2). Stack Trace: " + err); 
                    }
                    else{
                        callback("Success");
                    }

               }

            }

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Such a good question :-)

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem but now I found solution. You can remove item from your pending array just calling remove function on it, mongoose arrays implement that: http://jsdoc.info/SirUli/mongoose/types%7Carray.html#instance/remove

```
var acceptRequest = function(userId, requesterId, callback){

NotificationsReference.findOne({ id: userId}, function(err, result){
    if(err || result === null){
        callback("Could not accept notification. Stack: " + err);
    }else{
        var deletedRefId = 'unchanged';
        result.pending.remove(requesterId)
        result.save(callback(err))
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to find and update something, there are always two requests :-) You can try to add user reference to NotificationsReference via [populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html), and modify them right as you get NotificationsReference.